# How to center a table in HTML using external CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center a table on a HTML file. When I do it within the tag:

e.g. `table align="center",`

it seems to work. However, when I apply this in the external CSS file, it doesn't have any effect.

e.g. (in the external CSS) `table {align:center}`.

The same happens when I try doing this internally within the `<head><style></style></head>` tags.

What is the reason for why it's not working? (I'm mainly curious about why the align="center" works but the align:center (in css) doesn't). And if this way is incorrect then what are some alternatives?

I am using this table as a menu bar which should appear on every webpage so I do not want to continuously repeat the first-mentioned method. I'm quite new to HTML and CSS so any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you probably mean {align:center;} Right? It is not '='

Comment: Ahh yes sorry. I will edit.

Comment: Assign some `width` to your table and use `margin: auto;`. That's all you need.

Comment: Also there are lot of similar questions on how to center something and blog posts as well, search for it and try first.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions of other posts. I researched before but somehow missed some of them which had the answer I needed. Should I delete this question now?

Comment: "I am using this table as a menu bar ", this is an outdated approach. As you are just learning, don't start by learning bad practices. the `table` tag should be used for tabular data, that is it. There are plenty of tutorials out there on how to create a menu bar without using tables.

Answer (score 0):

Similar behavior to `align="center"` can be achieved with the following CSS:

```
table { margin: 0 auto; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
table { margin: 0px auto; }
```

or

```
table
{ 
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```